# Smart Card gives null as a value of private key

Tags: c#, smartcard, digital, gemalto

I am using a `Gemalto Smart card` to sign `XML` documents.

I have a method which returns the `certificate` and searches by the `thumbprint` that is hard coded.

I am unable to obtain the `private key` from that `Smart card` and sign the doc with it.

It returns `null` when I `debug` the app.

My goal is to get the `private key` and then ask the user for the `PIN` to authorize the signing of the document.

```
    public static X509Certificate2 GetDefaultCertificateStoredOnTheCard()
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true);

        // by thumbprint, there is only one
        certs = certs.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "6BB4F9D483206F44A992799541114536579CF2B3", true);

        if (certs.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Please insert smart card to obtain certificate.");
        }
        X509Certificate2 cert = certs[0];

        RSACryptoServiceProvider key;

        if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            // software cert
            key = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        }
        else
        {
            // certificate from smartcard
            CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider");
            csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
            key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
        }

        return cert;
    }
```

As you can see if the key is null,  set the `key` to use the `Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider`.

I have noticed on device manager that my `Smart Card Reader` is `Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader`.

Not sure if I should set something else here , it brings this window and an error with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very purpose of a smart card is to protect confidential data. There are no more confidential data than the private key (often this never leaves the smart card), so it is a  sign of correct functioning, that you don't get it.

Actually you have to let the smart card do the signature, probably by sending the hash value of your XML document.

Comment: Ok thank you guidot. I will look into how the smart card can do the signature further.

Comment: It seems that grozdeto talkes about `cert.PrivateKey` being `null` if the code provided is anything to go by, which is the *reference to* the private key. That should **not** be `null`. You might expect `null` for e.g. the private exponent, but that is not requested (and I'd expect a casting error or access related exception to happen rather than `null` to be returned).

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my question. The whole problem was the .dll. I installed wrongly another provider of electronic signature and it is using that .dll instead of the one that I used for the signing.

When I understood that, it was easy fix, just uninstall the app for the provider which uses the wrong .dll.